# symbolic c++ in GCC or microsoft visual c++

Tags: c++

can i use   Symbolic C++    features in linux c++ compiler or in visual c++ 2010? and also one question sometimes in programs there is such    headers  code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "symbolicc++.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 Symbolic x("x");
 cout << integrate(x+1, x);     // => 1/2*x^(2)+x
 Symbolic y("y");
 cout << df(y, x);              // => 0
 cout << df(y[x], x);           // => df(y[x],x)
 cout << df(exp(cos(y[x])), x); // => -sin(y[x])*df(y[x],x)*e^cos(y[x])
 return 0;
}
```

header   `#include "symbolicc++.h"`  i have tried

`#include " "` but it does not show me  symbolicc++.h so how to do it please give me a few example

```
there is such error after compile
symbolic.cpp:2:25: error: symbolicc++.h: No such file or directory
symbolic.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
symbolic.cpp:7: error: ‘Symbolic’ was not declared in this scope
symbolic.cpp:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘x’
symbolic.cpp:8: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
symbolic.cpp:8: error: ‘integrate’ was not declared in this scope
symbolic.cpp:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘y’
symbolic.cpp:10: error: ‘y’ was not declared in this scope
symbolic.cpp:10: error: ‘df’ was not declared in this scope
symbolic.cpp:12: error: ‘cos’ was not declared in this scope
symbolic.cpp:12: error: ‘exp’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: -1. Google + I get lucky gives you the actual answer (which is yes, provided you install it properly)

Comment: @Alexandre  how do you think why post here?because i have searched and dont understand so ask   people?why downvote?ok

Comment: i can't downvote  otherwise i will decrease you mark  for decrease my mark

Comment: @algorithms: don't take it personally. Your question is vague and suggest you didn't search at all.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html , download e.g. the SymbolicC++3 3.34 gzipped tar file.

Unpack that tar.gz file, and adjust your compiler/IDE to search for additional header files in the headers/subdir.

e.g. using a command line on Linux:

```
[nos@localhost ~]$ wget http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/sources/SymbolicC++3-3.34.tar.gz
16:20:24 (109.71 KB/s) - `SymbolicC++3-3.34.tar.gz' saved [155572/155572]
[nos@localhost ~]$ mkdir symbolicc++
[nos@localhost ~]$ cd symbolicc++/ &&  tar -xvzf ../SymbolicC++3-3.34.tar.gz   ; cd ..
[nos@localhost ~]$ gcc -Wall -I/home/nos/symbolicc++/headers -o myprogram myprogram.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Some clarification to extremely helpful nos answer - you have to change gcc into g++ compiler for newer versions of GNU compilers. Here is simple GNU Makefile that compiles `example/lagrange.cpp` example:

```
PROGRAM=legendre.cpp  #program to compile
LIB=../headers  #localization of headers of symbolicc++ library, specifically symbolicc++.h file

run:
    g++ -I$(LIB) -o main.x $(PROGRAM)
    (time ./main.x)

clean: main.x
    -rm main.x
```